# Avoid printing the repeated values in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have around 8 columns that are retrieved from the database using iReport.
For the first 3 columns, i want to print them only if their combination is unique.
Can someone help on this?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: I think you handle this with query itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new group to which assign the expression:

```
$F{var1} + "|" + $F{var2} + "|" + $F{var3}
```

where var1, var2 and var3 are the three columns whose combination must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to handle this in iReport. 
But you can handle this very easily with the query.

Comment: well, actually i will be fetching all the 8 columns(required) by using the query. Then, from the iReport i want to print only the unique combinations of first 3 columns. It the unique combination is repeated in the next record, that should be left blank.

Comment: I think you can do this using the variables. Create some variables. Assign the query results to this variables and play around it.